# UIProgressView - Progress Bar - SpriteKit / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uiprogressview

I'm hoping to use a `progress bar` to denote a percentage in my App.

I'm actually building it in Spritekit using Swift, so I'm hoping to do it programmatically, without the use of a storyboard etc.

I found [this awesome tutorial](http://rshankar.com/swift-demo-add-progress-bar/), but unfortunately I can't seem to add it to my `GameScene`/ worldNode...

How can I create a progress bar and add it to my GameScene, inside my SKView/Gamescene (not via ViewController)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use UIKit to make a progress bar. UIKit, I believe, is imported with SpriteKit but if it's not you can always import it. You'd want to make the progress bar using `UIProgress` class:

```
let prog = UIProgressView(frame: CGRectMake(your coordinates...))
//Set progress properties here (could also add a UILabel to show percentage from `progress` property
self.view.addSubview(prog)
```

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar needs to be placed in the `SKView` of the scene. You can access it via `scene.view` if you don't otherwise have a handle on it.

Here's an example in a playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import SpriteKit

let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300))
let scene = SKScene(size: view.frame.size)
view.presentScene(scene)

let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyle.Default)
progressView.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 150)

view.addSubview(progressView)
// alternately scene.view.addSubview(progressView)

progressView.progress = 0.5
view
```

Comment: Is this placed int he ViewController? Because then it makes it difficult to update from the Game scene...?

Comment: This is a playground. It's not placed in anyplace particular. (for example, the last `view` line is not something you'd normally see in code.) In Xcode, `File->New->Playground` and paste all the code into that.